# SolidWorks on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: wine, virtualbox, cad

I am a Bioengineering student who works with SolidWorks and I would like to be able to run it on Ubuntu 13.04. Short of having to install Windows, what methods are available and which works best?

If I were to use Virtualization and install Windows on a Virtual machine, is there anyway I can optimize graphic performance among other things? Is Wine a viable option for high intensity use?

Since everyone else in the department uses SolidWorks, I don't want to veer off and use unfamiliar software.

Answer (score 0):

Wine is a useful tool for running Windows applications however I wouldn't recommend it for graphics intensive programs (games, CAD, etc.) as these can create many bugs in Wine.

I think you would be better off with [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) which both allow you to run a virtual Windows OS inside Ubuntu.

To optimize your VM, see http://www.howtogeek.com/124796/the-htg-guide-to-speeding-up-your-virtual-machines/

Comment: Solidworks is mostly garbage with Wine (http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=318).

Answer (score -1):

For 3D Cads you have no choice, you have to install Windows.. I have the same problem. Unless you use less sophisticated cads for linux like Medusa amongst other. But Solidworks is the best, so just make a dual boot pc with Windows and Ubuntu. Use Windows for 3D Cad and Ubuntu for all other applications. You can always run Ubuntu from within Windows using a virtual machine (e.g. VirtualBox) that points to Ubuntu physical partition on your disk, so that when you use it in a virtualized environment you are actually making modifications you'll find when booting the machine with Ubuntu.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Thank you for your input. Your answer would be improved if you were to explain how your approach (running ubuntu in a VM) is different/preferable to minerz029 approach of (running windows in a VM)

Answer (score -1):

No Solidworks love for Ubuntu (or for linux, in general). Maybe try Freecad or BRL-CAD, but don't expect commercial-grade results. Siemens NX runs in some linuxes.

Answer (score -1):

Draftsight is the best alternative for AutoCAD in Linux system.

And, Solidwork in this time, you have to use in Windows platform.